# Points with integer coordinates

Tags: java

> Given a circle with centre(0,0) and radius r(integer>0), find the number of points(x,y) on the circumference such that x and y are both integers. A point(x,y) is considered to be on the circumference when x^2 + y^2 = r^2 .
>
> Input: A single line which is the radius of the circle.

I am unable to get the correct answers for this.  For example, if `radius` is 5, then there should be 12 points on the circumference, but I get just get 4.

The code I have written is:

```
static int findNumOfIntegerPoints(int radius)
{
    static int count =0;
    for (int x=0; x<=radius; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y <=radius; y++)
        {
            if ((x^2)+(y^2) == (radius^2))
            {
                count++;
            }
            continue;
        }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: At least try to put some effort.

Comment: Are you counting the negative integers?  If the center is at 0,0, at least some of the points on its circumference are going to be negative values.

Comment: Your edit, which added your attempt at a solution and also asked about a _specific_ problem with that solution, has changed your question into something that can be answered here.  (Note how you didn't get any answers before your edit, only downvotes.)  I have removed my downvote.

Comment: For future reference, I highly recommend Eric Lippert's "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" for advice on isolating bugs like this one.  It's one of several good articles listed at the bottom of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)'s "[ask]".

Answer (score 1):

> Given a circle with centre(0,0) and radius r(integer>0), find the
>   number of points(x,y) on the circumference such that x and y are both
>   integers. A point(x,y) is considered to be on the circumference when
>   x^2 + y^2 = r^2 .

I have modified your function so that it takes into account negative coordinates, which you overlooked. I've also corrected your `x^2` and `y^2` to call `Math.pow(x,2)` instead, as the Java `^` operator isn't what you want.

```
class Circle {
    static int findNumOfIntegerPoints(int radius)
    {
        int count =0;
        for (int x=-radius; x<=radius; x++)
        {
            for (int y=-radius; y <=radius; y++)
            {
                if (Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2) == Math.pow(radius,2))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(findNumOfIntegerPoints(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class coordinates {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int radius=0;
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    radius=obj.nextInt();
    int points=0;
    for(int x=-radius;x<=radius;x++)
    {
        for(int y=-radius;y<=radius;y++)
    {
    double dist=Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);

    if(dist==radius)
    {
    points++;
    }
    }
    }
    System.out.println("Total no of integer co-ordinates : "+points);
    obj.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]".  On Stack Overflow, code-only answers are generally considered unhelpful, because they don't explain _why_ the old code didn't work while the new code works (assuming it _does_ work...).